# Exponential smoothing method

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function in r for exponential smoothing.

I have been able to create what I need in excel using a formula:

```
=(alpha*observed+(alpha - 1)*previous)
```

This can easily be dragged down and achieves the desired result. Here is an example of this with alpha = 0.1.

```
Score <- c(4,7,3,5,7,2,3)

Score   Exp Smooth      Calculation
4       #N/A            #N/A
7       4               4
3       4.3             0.1*7+0.9*4
5       4.17            0.1*3+0.9*4.3
7       4.253           0.1*5+0.9*4.17
2       4.5277          0.1*7+0.9*4.253
3       4.27493         0.1*2+0.9*4.5277
```

I'm sure there must be a way to recreate this as a function in r.
Furthermore, I need this function to be able to be grouped over multiple fields. Here is another example with more fields and the desired exponential smoothing figures.

```
Player <- c('Y','Z','Z','Z','Z','Y','Y','Y','Y','Z','Y','Y','Z','Y','Z','Y','Z','Z','Y','Y','Z','Y','Z','Y','Z','Z','Y')
Team <- c('A','B','A','A','B','A','B','B','A','A','B','B','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','A','A','A','A')
Score <- c(5,2,7,3,9,6,3,7,1,7,3,8,3,4,1,9,4,6,3,8,3,4,1,9,4,6,6)
data.frame(Player, Team, Score)
```

Desired result:

```
Player  Team    Score   Exp Smooth
Y       A       5       #N/A            
Z       B       2       #N/A
Z       A       7       #N/A            
Z       A       3       7                
Z       B       9       2
Y       A       6       5
Y       B       3       #N/A
Y       B       7       3
Y       A       1       5.1
Z       A       7       6.6
Y       B       3       3.4
Y       B       8       3.36
Z       A       3       6.64
Y       A       4       4.69
Z       A       1       6.276
Y       A       9       4.621
Z       A       4       5.7484
Z       A       6       5.57356
Y       A       3       5.05890
Y       B       8       3.82400
Z       B       3       2.70000
Y       B       4       4.24160
Z       B       1       2.73000
Y       A       9       4.85301
Z       A       4       5.616204
Z       A       6       5.454584
Y       A       6       5.267709
```

I'm sure there must be a way to achieve this in r. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you elaborate on "grouped over multiple fields"? Does this entail the function be applied to a subset of combination of Y-A, Y-B, Z-A and Z-B?

Comment: Did you look at `forecast` package? You can find it [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf)

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Yes thats what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `filter` function. However, we have to be a bit creative since its recursive filter implies a coefficient of 1 for lag 0.

```
fun <- function(x) {
  res <- stats::filter(x * c(1, rep(0.1, length(x) - 1)), 0.9, method = "recursive")
  c(NA, res[-length(res)])
}

Score <- c(4,7,3,5,7,2,3)
fun(Score)
#[1]      NA 4.00000 4.30000 4.17000 4.25300 4.52770 4.27493
```

There is an enormous number of answers on Stack Overflow showing how to apply a function by groups ("split-apply-combine").

Comment: I get an error when I run your code? 
"Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: You are probably using package dplyr, which masks `filter`. Make it explicit that you want to use `stats::filter` in your code.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm trying to get the bottom table with grouping now. Previous functions I've used have worked using ave. I try ave(Score, Team, Player, FUN = fun) but get different figures?

Comment: @greeny Sorry, there was an artifact of testing in my function.

Comment: I have a follow on question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474622/exponential-smoothing-function-over-different-groups