# Exponential Smoothing Function Over Different Groups

Tags: r

I have a dataset:

```
Player <- c('Y','Z','Z','Z','Z','Y','Y','Y','Y','Z','Y','Y','Z','Y','Z','Y','Z','Z','Y','Y','Z','Y','Z','Y','Z','Z','Y')
Team <- c('A','B','A','A','B','A','B','B','A','A','B','B','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','A','A','A','A')
Score <- c(5,2,7,3,9,6,3,7,1,7,3,8,3,4,1,9,4,6,3,8,3,4,1,9,4,6,6)
data.frame(Player, Team, Score)
```

I have a function that performs exponential smoothing with alpha = 0.1:

```
fun <- function(x) {
 res <- stats::filter(x * c(1, rep(0.1, length(x) - 1)), 0.9, method = "recursive")
 c(NA, res[-length(res)])}
```

I then run this function over different groups.

```
EXP <- ave(Score, Player, Team, FUN = fun)
data.frame(Player, Team, Score, EXP)
```

which gives:

```
Player  Team    Score   EXP
Y       A       5       #N/A            
Z       B       2       #N/A
Z       A       7       #N/A            
Z       A       3       7                
Z       B       9       2
Y       A       6       5
Y       B       3       #N/A
Y       B       7       3
Y       A       1       5.1
Z       A       7       6.6
Y       B       3       3.4
Y       B       8       3.36
Z       A       3       6.64
Y       A       4       4.69
Z       A       1       6.276
Y       A       9       4.621
Z       A       4       5.7484
Z       A       6       5.57356
Y       A       3       5.05890
Y       B       8       3.82400
Z       B       3       2.70000
Y       B       4       4.24160
Z       B       1       2.73000
Y       A       9       4.85301
Z       A       4       5.616204
Z       A       6       5.454584
Y       A       6       5.267709
```

However I have two questions/requests on this:

1. Rather than giving NA's for the first row of each group I'd like to give the observed value x.
2. When a grouping has only one row to it, I would again like it to give the observed value x.

With those two amendments, this would give this as the desired result (I have added a one row subset to the bottom):

```
Player  Team    Score   Exp Smooth
Y       A       5       5           
Z       B       2       2
Z       A       7       7           
Z       A       3       7                
Z       B       9       2
Y       A       6       5
Y       B       3       3
Y       B       7       3
Y       A       1       5.1
Z       A       7       6.6
Y       B       3       3.4
Y       B       8       3.36
Z       A       3       6.64
Y       A       4       4.69
Z       A       1       6.276
Y       A       9       4.621
Z       A       4       5.7484
Z       A       6       5.57356
Y       A       3       5.05890
Y       B       8       3.82400
Z       B       3       2.70000
Y       B       4       4.24160
Z       B       1       2.73000
Y       A       9       4.85301
Z       A       4       5.616204
Z       A       6       5.454584
Y       A       6       5.267709
B       B       4       4
```

Is there a way to change the function to do this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please check if `fun <- function(x) {
 res <- stats::filter(x * c(1, rep(0.1, length(x) - 1)), 0.9, method = "recursive"); res}` returns what you actually want. I don't get why you'd want to repeat the first value.

Comment: I'm running regression over the exponential smoothing field and I can't have any NA values in it. It's just to replace the NA's are the start

Comment: `filter` does not return any NA values. The last line of the function removes the last value of what `filter` returns and pads with an NA in front, because you claimed that's what you want. It should be easy for you to adjust to pad with the first value of `x` instead (although mathematically that's dubious).

Comment: I have achieved the first part of what I need using your function but with `head(x,1)` instead of `NA`. This gives `fun <- function(x) {
  res <- stats::filter(x * c(1, rep(0.1, length(x) - 1)), 0.9, method = "recursive")
  c(head(x,1), res[-length(res)])
}`

Comment: I still am struggling to figure out part 2 of my request: how to not get an error when there is only one observation in a group? Is there a way to amend the function to handle this?